# Finding a string at the end of a line using shell_exec grep UNIX

Tags: php, shell, unix, grep

I'm trying to find a string at the end of a line in files using

```
shell_exec("grep -rl '=".$_GET['s']."$'");
```

This returns nothing but if i remove the $ it will return all matches (even if not at the end of the line.)

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There are PHP ways to do this. Explain what you are trying to find and someone will show you how to do this in PHP

Comment: I'm looking for someone who can help with fixing this: shell_exec("grep -rl '=".$_GET['s']."$'"); ... Or can explain why it doesn't work

Comment: Could it be that the file you are grepping, has CRLF line endings? I would proceed as follows: (1) Store the command which you are constructing, into a PHP variable, say `$cmd`, and print this variable. (2) Do a `shell_exec($cmd)`. (3) Verifying that it still doesn't work, copy the command printed in step (1) to the command line and see, whether or not it works. This will at least tell you whether the problem is on the PHP- or on the Shell-side.

Comment: @user1934428 you sent me in the right direction .. adding $'\r' solved it. is there a way to match \r or \n at the end of the line?

Comment: How about simply replacing `."$'"` by `."\r$'"`, or better yet by `."\r?$'"` to make it optional? Of course, if you know for sure, that there will always be a CR at the end of your files, you could simple use a dot in front of the final `$` (which matches any character), or you could use a tool like `dos2unix` to get rid of the CR. Of course, RiggsFolly is right when wondering why you do this with grep. If you handle it completely inside PHP, it will probably be easier.

Comment: @user1934428 I think that in this case shell_exec will work faster and will use less server resources, in php you'll need to use at least 2 php functions inside foreach to get the same results. anyways  ."\r$'" is not working but this does $'\r'

Comment: I found it risky to recommend `$'\r'`, because this is interpreted by the shell, and we don't know what shell you will be running. It is certainly understood by bash, but AFIK it is not in Posix (please correct me if I'm wrong), and I fear this might break if you are on a system where shell_exec starts a strict POSIX shell. As for performance, searching in PHP itself might be slower than in a compiled language (grep is written in C), but on the other hand your solution requires PHP to spawn a subprocess, which is not cheap either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: preg_match()

for searching strings, chars and file extensions in lines

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php